# 2 side by side same size fieldset

Tags: html, css, primefaces, fieldset

I'm designing a webpage with Primefaces but I think my problem is more general :

I want 2 fieldsets side by side that have the same size. How can I do it ?

Edit: The 2 fieldset are in a `<div>` with `height:auto; width:auto;`

Answer (score 2):

try this in css

```
fieldset{
width :50%;
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
display : inline-block;
}
```

Comment: what about for larger screens ?? you would have a margin in between no ?

Answer (score 0):

- Give each `<fieldset>` a width of 50%
- Float the first one to the left, float the second one to the right

Comment: Doing this, I get the second one right but also below the first.

Comment: Same result. Removing the width I can get them side by side. But how can they have the same height ?

Comment: you'll have to specify a height for them. either in css or dynamically using javascript